# Copy specific axes from figure to new figure

Tags: matlab, histogram, figure

Ive saved a figure as a .fig-file in MATLAB which I did now reopen after some time.

Is there a way to access the data which is saved in the Histogram? I want to replot it by using the `hist()` command instead of `imhist` into a new figure (the reason is that matlab2tikz cant export the histogram plotted by `imhist` properly).

I imagine I could access the data when I would know the handle of the histogram, right?

**EDIT:**

```
A = findall(gcf,'type','axes');
```

then inspecting

```
get(A(i))
```

to see which axes the histogram is plotted in. This works but I have to figure out how to retrieve the actual data.
But I somehow assume that I have to look at a parent/children of the axes handle (depending which hierarchy MATLAB creates of objects).

Comment: I'd say dig down the hierarchy 'til you can retrieve the `XData`, `YData`, etc. for the patch object - from that you _should_ be able to reconstruct at least the original bin counts and centres, except those that fall outside the axes.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out via `B = get(A(2)); C = get(B.Children)` where as `C` contains the `X/YData`. Quite nested stuff in MATLAB :D But it still makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out finally.
As written in my edit above, you can use `findall` to find the handles of all axes-objects.
After using it, try to find out which handle refers to which axes by looking at the entries like `X/YLim` in `get(A(i))`, after finding the axes-ID and storing it (the `k`-th element in A) to `idx = A(K)`, use this script to read the entries from the histogram plotted by `imhist()` -> The values are replicated as often as described by the bins (`YData`) and then replotted by `hist` into a new figure:

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------- %
b = get(idx);
b = get(b.Children); % Get the Plot-Handle
x = b.XData; % Bins
y = b.YData; % Bin-Counts

data = [];
for i = 1:length(x)
    data = [data x(i)*ones(1,y(i))]; % replicate data
end

figure
hist(data, length(unique(x)));
xlim([min(data) max(data)]);
```

Edit: The for-loop is a quick and dirty one ;-) Im sure there's a nicer solution e.g. by using `repmat`, but I was only interested in a quick solution :-)